# Angular & TypeScript - Creating interfaces for nested objects

Tags: angular, typescript, interface

I've spent a lot if time trying to apply some interfaces to the JSON response i get from the API. It does work in the browser when it's compiled, but my IDE vs code gives me this error
**Identifier 'title' is not defined. 'RoomItem[]' does not contain such a member**.

It does show the elements, my vs code just marks the data properties with a red underline in the view. Meanwhile all this, my terminal pops this warning on me too.

**WARNING in AngularCompilerPlugin: Forked Type Checker exited unexpectedly. Falling back to type checking on main thread.**

Could anyone please help me, I would appreciate it so much - have a nice day developers!

```
// JSON Response

area: "21 - 28 m²"
day_price_flex: "1647.00"
day_price_normal: "1318.00"
description: "Vores flotte superiorværelser tilbyder mere plads til at slappe af på efter en lang dag på ferien. Se en film på TV'et eller nyd lidt afslapning i badekarret."
facilities: (12) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
id: "2"
images: [{…}]
num_facilities: 12
num_images: 1
num_persons: "2"
title: "Superior"

// Facilities

facilities: Array(12)
0: {id: "1", title: "Elkedel med kaffe/te", category: "Generelt udstyr"}
1: {id: "2", title: "Fri WiFi", category: "Generelt udstyr"}
2: {id: "3", title: "Hårtørrer", category: "Generelt udstyr"}
3: {id: "4", title: "Ikke-ryger", category: "Generelt udstyr"}
4: {id: "5", title: "Luftkøling", category: "Generelt udstyr"}
5: {id: "6", title: "Minibar", category: "Generelt udstyr"}
6: {id: "7", title: "Mørklægningsgardiner", category: "Generelt udstyr"}
7: {id: "8", title: "Pengeskab", category: "Generelt udstyr"}
8: {id: "9", title: "Strygebræt og strygejern", category: "Generelt udstyr"}
9: {id: "10", title: "Fransk altan (tilgængelig i nogle værelser)", category: "Generelt udstyr"}
10: {id: "25", title: "To separate enkeltsenge", category: "Senge"}
11: {id: "26", title: "King-size seng", category: "Senge"}

// Images

0: {id: "75", title: "Superior Soveplads ©", image: "/images/room-superior-bedroom.jpg"}
```

```
// HTML / View

<section *ngIf="http.data | async as data">
    <article>
        <h2>{{data.title}}</h2>
        <h5>{{data.area}}</h5>
        <p>{{data.description}}</p>
    </article>
</section>
```

```
// http.service.ts

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError, shareReplay } from 'rxjs/operators';

interface Facilities {
  id?: string;
  title?: string;
  category?: string;
}

interface Images {
  id?: string;
  title?: string;
  image?: string;
}

interface RoomItem {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  description: string;
  num_persons: string;
  area: string;
  day_price_normal: string;
  day_price_flex: string;
  num_images: number;
  images?: Images[];
  num_facilities: number;
  facilities?: Facilities[];
}

interface Response {
  status: boolean;
  error: string;
  item?: RoomItem[];
  items?: RoomItem[];
}


const CACHE_SIZE = 1;

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HttpService {
  private cache$: Observable<RoomItem[]>;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  
   get data() {
    if (!this.cache$) {
      this.cache$ = this.requestRoom(2).pipe(shareReplay(CACHE_SIZE));
    }
    
    return this.cache$;
   }

   private requestRoom(id) {
     return this.http.get<Response>(`https://api.mediehuset.net/overlook/rooms/${id}`).pipe(
       map(response => response.item ? response.item : response.items)
     );
   }

}
```

The thing is, i've now tried to remove the array part of my type,
but it would not compile and that's because i use a map operator on it - which wouldn't be possible if it weren't an array..

```
// If i change my cache observable to not having it:

Observable<RoomItem>

// I had to change it in my Response type as well..

interface Response {
  status: boolean;
  error: string;
  item?: RoomItem;
  items?: RoomItem;
}

// I actually also tried with RoomItem<Object>, with compilation success but no results on the functioning part of it.
```

As i wrote, it wouldn't work that time - because of compilation error.. So what to do, it's only my IDE that tells me i'm wrong, it still compiles and does the right thing by showing my the items?

So when i do a wrong code popping red underlines in my IDE, i guess i shouldn't worry when making code that makes sense in a kind of way.
This was for testing purposes, and surely i should make the interfaces have their own files, to get imported in the other respective locations of use.

Comment: It may seems to you are added `RoomItem[]` instead of `RoomItem` in your response?

Comment: Thanks for the input, but when i try do that i get CANNOT GET/

ERROR in src/app/services/http.service.ts:75:7 - error TS2322: Type 'Observable<RoomItem | RoomItem[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<RoomItem[]>'.
  Type 'RoomItem | RoomItem[]' is not assignable to type 'RoomItem[]'.
    Type 'RoomItem' is missing the following properties from type 'RoomItem[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.

75       this.cache$ = this.requestRoom(2).pipe(shareReplay(CACHE_SIZE));

If i try to remove the '[]' everywhere there is RoomItem[] then it wont work either..

Answer (score 0):

In service, you are returning different responses based on a condition, one item `{ }` or items `[ ]`. So you cast its return type to both like `Observable< RoomItem | RoomItem[]>`

#### service

```
get data(): Observable< RoomItem | RoomItem[]> {
        if (!this.cache$) {
            this.cache$ = this.requestRoom(2).pipe(shareReplay(CACHE_SIZE));
        }

        return this.cache$;
    }

    private requestRoom(id) {
        return this.http
            .get<Response>(`https://api.mediehuset.net/overlook/rooms/${id}`)
            .pipe(map((response) => (response.item ? response.item : response.items)));
    }
```

#### HTML

```
<section *ngIf="http.data | async as data">
    <article *ngIf="!isDataAnArray(data); else displayArrayData">
        <h2>{{data.title}}</h2>
        <h5>{{data.area}}</h5>
        <p>{{data.description}}</p>
    </article>
    <ng-template #displayArrayData>
      <article>
       <div *ngFor="let item of data">
            <h2>{{item.title}}</h2>
            <h5>{{item.area}}</h5>
            <p>{{item.description}}</p>
        </div> 
    </article>
    </ng-template>
</section>
```

#### component

```
isDataAnArray(data: RoomItem | RoomItem[]){
        retun Array.isArray(data);
    }
```

#### interface definition

```
interface Response {
  status: boolean;
  error: string;
  item?: RoomItem;
  items?: RoomItem[];
}
```

Comment: I tried to change the things you described, but still have the red underlines -
**Identifier 'title' is not defined. 'RoomItem | RoomItem[]' does not contain such a member**

Comment: @Malthe, change your type to `item?: RoomItem;` in `Response`, check the updated answer